# Cron job not handling authenticated method too well

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cron

I have a cron job running on Heroku, but the method I am running requires basic HTTP authentication.

I am wondering if cron job can actually enter in the username and password for the HTTP authentication and run the cron job.

Do you think this is possible?

---

Edit

My code for cron job looks something like below

Application controller

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery

      private
        def authenticate
          authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic("Coverages") do |username, password|
          username == "xxx" && password == "xxx"
        end
      end
    end
```

Method to run with cron job

```
class CoveragesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def method_to_run_with_cron_job
  end
end
```

Cron Job

```
namespace :cron do
  desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
  task :cron => :environment do
    if Time.now.hour == 18 # run at midnight
      Display.show
    end
  end
end
```

---

edit 2

Basically, the cron job method should run a method that has an http authentication like this.

[image]

So i am wondering if cronjob method can enter in username and password when it runs the method.

Comment: Can you share some more information? Is your cron job invoking an HTTP request? Are you using the authenticate_with_http_basic method from ActionController?

Comment: Yep, I'm also confused about the HTTP thing when you're talking about cron jobs.  Looks like we're missing the most vital code to help you. On a whim, I'm going to suggest you want to use something like the rest-client gem to specify the HTTP credentials for the request.